# Is there a way to demonstrate the relationship between many pairs of variables over time?

Tags: modeling

I'm conducting research where I hope to show the relationship between two groups in how they discuss an issue. I have lots of press releases from both sides, and information on those press releases - namely which of the two groups they belong to, what date they were released, and which arguments of a series of potential arguments featured in the document. So in the dataset, my cases are press releases, and my variables are `group`, `date`, and variables measuring the frequency of arguments `a1` `a2` `a3` etc.

I'm hoping to demonstrate that the use of arguments by one group brings about an increase in use of that same argument by the other group over time. A simple but non-rigorous way to do this would be to show it graphically for each argument - put time on the x-axis, argument frequency on the y-axis, and plot two lines for argument use over time by group. However, I was hoping someone better versed on statistical techniques than I could point me to an actual model that could better show this sort of relationship, perhaps one that could demonstrate the relationship for multiple arguments at once. Any ideas?